# Unable to deploy EAR file to Azure App Service using JBOSS EAP 7

Tags: java, azure, azure-web-app-service, redhat, jboss7.x

I am unable to deploy EAR file into Azure App Service with JBOSS EAP 7.3.6.

I tried following steps as described in the documentation found at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip?tabs=cli#deploy-warjarear-packages).

Out of given 4 options, allowed to use either Azure CLI or Kudu API since EAR is not supported by Azure Powershell and Kudu UI not supporting any.

1. Using Azure CLI, tried executing following command.,

   `az webapp deploy --resource-group test-rg --name dmap --src-path C:\Users\HP\Desktop\DMAP.ear`

   Getting error as

   ***CommandNotFoundError: 'deploy' is misspelled or not recognized by the system.*
   Did you mean 'deployment' ?
   Still stuck? Run 'az webapp --help' to view all commands or go to
   'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest' to learn
   more**
2. Using Kudu API, tried executing following command.,

   `curl -X POST -u dmap --data-binary @"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\DMAP.ear" https://dmap.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/publish&type=ear`

   Getting response as

   **The system cannot find the file specified.**

   Searching for this response, I found this [link](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/683) where it comes for successful deployment too. Assuming it I tried to access my application using link **https://dmap.azurewebsites.net/DMAPWeb**. But it shows nothing found.

   To verify the deployment, I checked folder **/site/wwwroot** using FTP but I don't see any files deployed.

Could you please guide me here and clarify where I am wrong.

Comment: Have you tried the same command via Cloud Shell ?

Comment: Not tried. Will check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have tested this in our local environment it is working fine. Below statements are based on our analysis.

Using the Below Azure CLI cmdlet , we have tried deploying the .ear file from local machine to web app (deployed in azure ) operation got succeeded without any issues.

**Here is the cmdlet we have used :**

```
az webapp deploy --resource-group <rgName> --name <webAppName> --src-path c:\Users\Downloads\<fileName>.ear ##Path of .ear file
```

**Here is the Sample output for reference:**

[image]

**Note:**
If you are deploying from local machine run the `az.cmd(AzureCLI)` in admin mode. By default `az.cmd` will be under the path   `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin` in your local machine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Venkatesh. But when running cmd '''az webapp deploy --resource-group test_rg --name dmap --src-path C:\Users\HP\Desktop\DMAP.ear''' from path '''Ran it from path c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin''' getting error as '''CommandNotFoundError: 'deploy' is misspelled or not recognized by the system.
Did you mean 'deployment' ?
Still stuck? Run 'az webapp --help' to view all commands or go to 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest' to learn more'''

Comment: @sureshd, the above error states that a particular cmdlet was not found or misspelled & the cmdlet execution failed with the above error & the deployment didn't start
Have you installed az CLI in your local machine from where you are trying to deploy?

Comment: yes Azure CLI is installed. Below output I got for version check.                             az --version
azure-cli                         2.14.0 *

core                              2.14.0 *
telemetry                          1.0.6

Python location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\python.exe'
Extensions directory 'C:\Users\HP\.azure\cliextensions'

Python (Windows) 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 23 2018, 23:31:17) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]

Comment: Sorry, I am late to update. After reinstalling Azure CLI, it got worked.

Comment: do you know what is the wrong with Kudu API used to submit EAR file

Comment: @sureshd -  Glad to hear that i can help you If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Comment: @sureshd - for the help regarding `what is wrong with Kudu API used to submit EAR file`, Could you please raise a new request in the stack for faster response as I am not aware of the issue.